# Running .app/.exe file in java

Tags: java, windows, macos

I'm fairly new to java programming and could use some help. I'm writing a launcher for a game I am creating. It is made within unity so it compiles to macs and PCs with different files. I am stuck on how to execute both the .exe files for windows and the .app files for mac. I have already written code to determine what OS the java program is being run from. Any help with you could provide will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), it will allow you to execute external commands and has a number of help properties, such as providing a means to set the start directory for the command.

Windows is pretty straight forward, as you simply run the executable, but on Macs you need to specify the executable directly.  A .app bundle is just a directory with configuration.

You can also try `Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("MyLineInInput.app"));` (which will probably work on Widnows to)